# Converting Year - Week to days of the week - PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

| Year&Week | Year | Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-50 | 2022 | 50 |
| 2022-51 | 2022 | 51 |
| 2022-52 | 2022 | 52 |

I would like to convert that information by adding a new column that reflects the last day (sunday) and the initial day (monday) of the weeks. So my final dataframe should looks like the following:

| Year&Week | Year | Week | Initial day of week | Last day of week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-50 | 2022 | 50 | 12/Dec/2022 | 18/Dec/2022 |
| 2022-51 | 2022 | 51 | 19/Dec/2022 | 25/Dec/2022 |
| 2022-52 | 2022 | 52 | 26/Dec/2022 | 01/Jan/2023 |

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and create `date` base:

- `%W`: The week number of the year
- `%Y`: The year number
- `%a`: Weekday, short version
- `%b`: The first three characters of the month name
- `%d`: The day of the month

```
df['Initial day of week'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Week'].astype(str) + df['Year'].astype(str) + 'Mon', format='%W%Y%a'
).dt.strftime("%d/%b/%Y")

df['Last day of week'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Week'].astype(str) + df['Year'].astype(str) + 'Sun', format='%W%Y%a'
).dt.strftime("%d/%b/%Y")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Year&Week  Year  Week Initial day of week Last day of week
0   2022-50  2022    50         12/Dec/2022      18/Dec/2022
1   2022-51  2022    51         19/Dec/2022      25/Dec/2022
2   2022-52  2022    52         26/Dec/2022      01/Jan/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `datetime` module to convert `2022-50` which is probably is in the "%Y%W" Format to `M/d/y` format, like the below's peace of codes:

```
from datetime import datetime

input_date = "2022-50"
right_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y-%W")   
formate_date_reult = right_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

print(formate_date_reult) # Output is: 12/25/2022
```